How can I find the used compression algorithm of a file from its input and output?
I have some text files that encoded and compressed. I have the output file, but I don’t know the compression algorithm. Could you please help me to find the used algorithm?
I found the following facts about this algorithm:

Each file consists maximum 8 lines.
Each line consist exactly 123 character (including spaces)
The output file is using a compression method.
The output file starts with the bytes 00 00, indicating the beginning of the compressed data.
Unrepeated characters are encoded using their ASCII values.
If one character repeated more than 4 times, it will coded as
“00”+ number of repeated character+ repeated character
For example, if 'A' appears 5 times, it would be encoded as 00 05 41
Number of characters that continuously coded in ASCII are multiply by 4 and mentioned before each coded group.
The compressed algorithm shouldn’t be so complicated, because these files belongs to year 2000.

I have 3,000 couple of input and output. Following is a sample: (if you open the output file in a hex editor, I’ll be clearer.)
Input:
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120450 F0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y071115           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR       
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120500 K0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y116160           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR       
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120700 K0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y071115           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR      
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0121100 K0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y071115           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR      
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0121250 F0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y296340           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR       
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0122475 T0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y071115           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR       
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0122575 T0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y296340           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR       
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0126425 T0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y                                    YESILKOY APP RADAR       

Output (hexadecimal):
00 00 BC 53 4D 45 53 50 20 4C 54 46 4D 4C 54 56
41 50 50 30 31 32 30 34 35 30 20 46 30 20 20 20
52 41 20 4E 34 31 31 36 33 31 30 30 45 30 32 38
34 35 9D 0C 30 37 30 00 07 20 1C 59 30 37 31 31
31 35 00 0B 20 B1 24 08 50 41 00 0B 20 48 59 45
53 49 4C 4B 4F 59 20 41 50 50 20 52 41 44 41 52
00 07 20 03 B5 07 57 B9 07 35 30 30 20 4B D7 12
01 31 31 36 31 36 C3 BF 07 83 B0 07 91 2F 83 B9
07 C3 6F 0F 43 64 0F CB BF 07 31 31 C3 BE 07 47
CA 1E 32 D7 1F 17 32 39 36 33 34 03 13 17 DB 6F
0F 32 34 37 35 20 54 83 6D 0F 4B BA 07 32 35 C3
6F 0F 43 64 0F 0F BA 07 36 34 32 00 24 20 43 B6
07

In above example:

00 00: show starting the output file
BC: is equal to 188.  188/4= 47. 47 is the number of ASCII characters that coded continuously.
53 4D 45 …. 38 34 35: is equal “SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120450 F0   RA N41163100E02845” in ASCII.
9D 0C: ?????
30 37 30: equal “070” is ASCII.
00 07 20: equal to 7 spaces
1C: is equal 28. 28/4=7. 7 is the number of ASCII characters that coded continuously.
And so on…

hexdump -C -R 79058622o.bin
000000  00 00 bc 53 4d 45 53 50 20 4c 54 46 4d 4c 54 56  ..¼SMESP LTFMLTV
000010  41 50 50 30 31 32 30 34 35 30 20 46 30 20 20 20  APP0120450 F0
000020  52 41 20 4e 34 31 31 36 33 31 30 30 45 30 32 38  RA N41163100E028
000030  34 35 9d 0c 30 37 30 00 07 20 1c 59 30 37 31 31  45.070.. .Y0711
000040  31 35 00 0b 20 b1 24 08 50 41 00 0b 20 48 59 45  15.. ±$.PA.. HYE
000050  53 49 4c 4b 4f 59 20 41 50 50 20 52 41 44 41 52  SILKOY APP RADAR
000060  00 07 20 03 b5 07 57 b9 07 35 30 30 20 4b d7 12  .. .µ.W¹.500 K×.
000070  01 31 31 36 31 36 c3 bf 07 83 b0 07 91 2f 83 b9  .11616Ã¿.ƒ°.‘/ƒ¹
000080  07 c3 6f 0f 43 64 0f cb bf 07 31 31 c3 be 07 47  .Ão.Cd.Ë¿.11Ã¾.G
000090  ca 1e 32 d7 1f 17 32 39 36 33 34 03 13 17 db 6f  Ê.2×..29634...Ûo
0000a0  0f 32 34 37 35 20 54 83 6d 0f 4b ba 07 32 35 c3  .2475 Tƒm.Kº.25Ã
0000b0  6f 0f 43 64 0f 0f ba 07 36 34 32 00 24 20 43 b6  o.Cd..º.642.$ C¶
0000c0  07                                               .



You have to take an educated guess and then test that hypothesis. It looks to me like some sort of repeat any duplicated sections that have already been seen in a sliding buffer. LHA would be my first guess (it dates back to 1988 and was very good in its day - and still pretty good even now). Your best bet might be to find an app from that era that can decode most compressed formats and hope that it recognises it! Don't underestimate the sophistication of compression code back then disk space was expensive so good compression was very important. Otherwise decode a few by hand.

I mocked this up in Excel using VBA as a coffee time puzzle and got some way toward solving it after adding some fixup code to make my code behave in the same odd way as the original encoder. It was never good and I have lost interest in it but thought you might find this a useful start.
It does the first line almost perfectly but encodes it with escape sequences in ASCII text rather than binary. Encoding byte count shown as "(bytecount), RLE shown as {count," "}, and a reverse lookup reference as [-distance, matchlength, "stringfound"]. There is a flag to switch terse mode on where the output is now very close to the target binary file. It is useful to look at the first line and the pattern matches within it to illustrate how it works (first occurence in top line in bold and second occurrence below it also in bold:
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120450 F0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y071115           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120450 F0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y071115           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR
This is the full text analysed in Excel (I concatenated the lines into A26) it should be placed on Sheet1 :
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120450 F0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y071115           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120500 K0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y116160           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120700 K0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y071115           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0121100 K0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y071115           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0121250 F0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y296340           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0122475 T0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y071115           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0122575 T0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y296340           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0126425 T0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y
hexdump -C  -R  79058622o.bin
00  00  00  bc  53  4d  45  53  50  20  4c  54  46  4d  4c  54  56      ..¼SMESP    LTFMLTV
10  41  50  50  30  31  32  30  34  35  30  20  46  30  20  20  20      APP0120450  F0
20  52  41  20  4e  34  31  31  36  33  31  30  30  45  30  32  38      RA  N41163100E028
30  34  35  9d  0c  30  37  30  00  07  20  1c  59  30  37  31  31      45.070..    .Y0711
40  31  35  00  0b  20  b1  24  08  50  41  00  0b  20  48  59  45      15..    ±$.PA.. HYE
50  53  49  4c  4b  4f  59  20  41  50  50  20  52  41  44  41  52      SILKOY  APP RADAR
60  00  07  20  03  b5  07  57  b9  07  35  30  30  20  4b  d7  12      ..  .µ.W¹.500   K×.
70  01  31  31  36  31  36  c3  bf  07  83  b0  07  91  2f  83  b9      .11616Ã¿.ƒ°.‘/ƒ¹
80  07  c3  6f  0f  43  64  0f  cb  bf  07  31  31  c3  be  07  47      .Ão.Cd.Ë¿.11Ã¾.G
90  ca  1e  32  d7  1f  17  32  39  36  33  34  03  13  17  db  6f      Ê.2×..29634...Ûo
a0  0f  32  34  37  35  20  54  83  6d  0f  4b  ba  07  32  35  c3      0.2475  Tƒm.Kº.25Ã
b0  6f  0f  43  64  0f  0f  ba  07  36  34  32  00  24  20  43  b6      o.Cd..º.642.$   C¶
c0  07  .
SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120450 F0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y071115           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR       SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120500 K0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y116160           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR       SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120700 K0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y071115           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR      SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0121100 K0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y071115           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR      SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0121250 F0   RA N41163100E028450700          Y296340           LTFMLTPA           YESILKOY APP RADAR
(51)"SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120450 F0   RA N41163100E028450700{10," "}(7)"Y071115{11," "}-73, 6"LTFMLT"""PA {10," "}YESILKOY APP RADAR{7," "}[-124, 20]500 K[-124, 37]11616[-17, 11] [-124, 65]7[-124, 41]071115 [-124, 53][-123, 19]1100 K[-123, 118]250 F0[-123, 36]29634[-17, 11] [-123, 43]
(52)"SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120450 F0   RA N41163100E028450700 "9," ""Y071115"[11," "]-73, 6, "LTFMLT""PA"11," ""YESILKOY APP RADAR "[6," "]-123, 20, "SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120""500 K0   "-123, 33, "RA N41163100E028450700          Y""116160 "[10,""]-196, 6, "LTFMLT""PA"11,"""YESILK"[-123, 39, "OY APP RADAR       SMESP LTFMLTVAPP0120"]
bc                                                          9d,0c       0,7,20      0, b, 20    b1,24,8             0,7,20,3        0,b,20
-79             H           b5,7,57 b9,7            85
47                                                                                                      -75 -71
Due to vaguaries of how text transfers to and from this platform you may find that A26 the line with concatenated source material on has shifted up or down by +/-1. You will have to retype the formula in A26 "=A1 & chr(3) & A2 & chr(3) & ..." if you want to alter the lines being encoded.
This is the VBA sourcecode to process it and find partial matches.
Dim firstline As Boolean
Dim verbose As Boolean

Sub LookBack(ByRef target As Integer, start As Integer, ByRef stride As Integer, s As String)
  st = start
  tt = target
  If (tt < start - 128) Then tt = start - 128 '' maximum lookback for top bit set
  bestmatch = stride
  inc = 0
  besttarget = target
  While (tt < start - stride)
     While Mid(s, tt + inc, 1) = Mid(s, start + inc, 1)
        inc = inc + 1
     Wend
  If inc >= bestmatch Then
     bestmatch = inc
     besttarget = tt
  End If
  inc = 0
  tt = tt + 1
Wend
target = besttarget ' returms the nearest target with the lomgest possible match length
End Sub

Function OutputRLE(t, i, rle, och)
      OutputRLE = OutputString(t, rle)
      Debug.Print "RLE " & OutputRLE
      temp = "{" & rle & ",""" & och & """}" ' unclear if this applies to any character
      OutputRLE = OutputRLE & temp
      Debug.Print i - rle, temp
End Function

Function OutputString(t, n)
  good = Len(t) - n - 1
  OutputString = ""
  If (good > 0) Then
     If verbose Then OutputString = "(" & good & ")"""
     OutputString = OutputString & Left(t, good)
  End If
End Function

Function FormatMatch(s, target, match, i)
    temp = "[" & target + match - i & ", " & match & ""
    If verbose Then temp = temp & """" & Mid(s, target, match) & """"""
    temp = temp & "]"
    Debug.Print i - 2 * match + 1, temp, """" & Mid(s, target, match) & """"""
    FormatMatch = temp
''    FormatMatch = Left(temp, Len(temp) - match - 4) & "]" '' terse version without lookup string in quotes
End Function

Sub parse()
   Dim x(128) As Integer
   Dim target As Integer, start As Integer, match As Integer
   Dim s As String
   och = Chr(0)
   For i = 0 To 127
     x(i) = 0
   Next i
  ''  s = Cells(1, 1) '' to just process one line
   s = Cells(26, 1)
   match = 0
   start = 1
   rle = 1
   Debug.Print Len(s)
   Debug.Print s
   Debug.Print "00000000011111111112222222222233333333334444444444555555555666666666677777777778888888888999999999900000000001111111111222222222223333333332"
   Debug.Print "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
   outstr = ""
   firstline = True
   verbose = True
   For i = 1 To Len(s)
      ch = Mid(s, i, 1)
      t = t & ch
      If ch = "S" Then
        t = t '' debugging hook
      End If
      If ch = Chr(3) Or ch = Chr(13) Then
         firstline = False
         verbose = False   '' comment this out to get full annotation of quoted strings
      End If
      If ch <> Chr(10) Then
         If (ch = och) And (match < 2) And firstline Then
            rle = rle + 1
         Else
         If rle > 4 Then
            outstr = outstr & OutputRLE(t, i, rle, och)
            t = ch
            target = 0
            match = 0
         End If
         rle = 1
         vch = Asc(ch) 
  
         If (x(vch) > 0) Or target > 0 Then
     
            If target = 0 Then
               start = i
               target = x(vch)
            End If
            If target > 0 Then
               If ch = Mid(s, target + match, 1) Then
                  match = match + 1
                  If match = 1 And Not (firstline And och = " ") Then
                      Call LookBack(target, start, match, s) '' modifies target
                  End If
               Else
                  If match > 3 Then
                     outstr = outstr & OutputString(t, match)
                     t = ch
                     outstr = outstr & FormatMatch(s, target, match, i)
                  Else
                     t = t '' debugging hook
                  End If '' Match >3
                  target = 0
                  match = 0
              End If ' target > 0
            End If
         Else
            x(vch) = i '' first occurence of character
         End If  ' x(vch) = 0
      End If ' ch= och for RLE
      End If ' ch<>10
      och = ch
   Next i
   If rle > 4 Then outstr = outstr & OutputRLE(t, i, rle, och)
   Cells(28, 1) = outstr
   End Sub

It uses a fairly standard method with no attempts at go faster code to keep it simple. Worth noting here that with a record length of <128 bytes it is always possible to reference the entire of the previous line (unless you make the same mistake that the original authors did). They index back from the end of the matching section which complicates things later on. Also worth noting that the three byte encoding of runs of spaces is wasteful since after the first occurrence a two byte copy from buffer escape is shorter.
I have left lookups in the normal order of [distance, match] the original program encoded it as [distance+match, match] which complicates things since reverse indexes exceeding 128 have to be escaped with an extra byte. The code in its present form could be improved by disabling the RLE part altogether.
I haven't been able to figure out the crazy logic of their 3 byte lookup codes which have a 7 as the second byte and gave up at that point. I can see no merit in the byte count (multiplied by 4) for printable strings either (which only happens on the very first line). It just wastes another byte.
